# Can /consoleText be made the default console page in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

Is there any setting I can change in Jenkins to make `/consoleText` the default page for console outputs? Right now, I have to click on console, and then click on the `View as plain text` link to get this page.

PS: I'm open to "hack" suggestions, if there's no way to officially do this in Jenkins.

**Edit:** While I'd be perfectly happy with just making `/consoleText` as the default page, what would be even better would be to replace the `View as plain text` link with a `View dynamic log` link, so that I can access the `console` link too, in case I need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Sidebar-Link Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sidebar-Link+Plugin) which will give you the ability to add side links on various Jenkins pages like the build, top level, etc.